# Editing & Running an SQL Query in an Access database from Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to write a Excel VBA macro that runs a query based upon a variable in the spreadsheet. The existing data is half in a large data base (MS Access) on the network.

For some reason when my code runs, nothing is pasted back to my spreadsheet. Can you see why this may be the case:

```vb
Sub test()

    Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
    Dim ConnectionString As String
    Dim StrQuery As String


    ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=\\network\data07\version6.mdb;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString
    cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

    StrQuery = "SELECT dbo_vwData_SelectAll.BusinessDate, , dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Flowdate, dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Bucket FROM dbo_vwData_SelectAll WHERE (((dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Line)=""1.1.1.4"") AND ((dbo_vwData_SelectAll.ReferenceID) Like ""rent*"");"

    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

End Sub
```

The above is a test - I will be changing `"rent*"` for other variables based on strings in the spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to see what is inside rst? Take the generated query and run it on the Access Database directly to verify that the query is valid and what data you are suppose to get.

Comment: Have you confirmed that your 'rst' actually returns rows? i.e. is it a retrieval issue, or a paste issue?

Comment: Two consecutive commas represent a syntax error.

Comment: Further to Dan's point, perhaps checks the Errors collection on the connection.

Comment: Better use single quotes around the constant values in your query i.s.o double quotes which go around column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The misappropriated `LIKE` operator is a known issue in the MS Access SQL dialect. When using MSAccess.exe GUI program, `LIKE` uses the asterisk wildcard, `*`. However, using MS Access via ODBC as a backend database as you are with Excel, `LIKE` uses the ANSI wildcard, `%`. See MS Office Support docs on [Access wildcard character reference](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-wildcard-character-reference-af00c501-7972-40ee-8889-e18abaad12d1).

Therefore, consider the following adjustment which includes use of single quotes:

```sql
SELECT dbo_vwData_SelectAll.BusinessDate,
       dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Flowdate, dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Bucket 

FROM dbo_vwData_SelectAll

WHERE (((dbo_vwData_SelectAll.Line)='1.1.1.4') 
  AND  ((dbo_vwData_SelectAll.ReferenceID) LIKE 'rent%');
```

To be consistent in either frontend or backend interfaces, consider the `ALIKE` operator:

```sql
AND  ((dbo_vwData_SelectAll.ReferenceID) ALIKE 'rent%');
```

Comment: Perfect. That was where it was tripping up. Thank you.